# How to change the width of the featured image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Currently I am using sparkling theme.. I need to to use featured image for the background of the header..

For example, 
I want the featured image need to look like below screenshot
[image]

But what I am getting is,

[image]

I dont know how to resize the image and giving large width. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: I installed this theme myself in a test environment and found that the image is inside a wrapper that prevents the image from being able to stretch full width by increasing the image size via `add_image_size()` or by adding `width:100%` to the style rules. This answer won't actually provide the solution as the solution involves reworking several theme files.**

After looking at the [theme code on gitHub](https://github.com/puikinsh/Sparkling) I see that the image being used is using a custom size specified by this line of code found in [functions.php](https://github.com/puikinsh/Sparkling/blob/master/functions.php#L64):

```
add_image_size( 'sparkling-featured', 750, 410, true );
```

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/ for an explanation of what that code does.

And being called by this line in [content-single.php](https://github.com/puikinsh/Sparkling/blob/master/content-single.php#L8):

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'sparkling-featured', array( 'class' => 'single-featured' ));
```

You could may want to update the image size in the `add_image_size()` call so that it uses a larger size by default. Once you have the image size you need (if you changed it) you can target it by classname and apply some style rules in the style.css file so that it stretches the full width of the container.

```
.single-featured{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

NOTE: the container width may not be 100% the width of the page - without a link to an example page or installing the theme and testing myself I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You're using wordpress sparkling theme.  It looks like they're using a plugin "FlexSlider".  This plugin should do it for you.

If that does not work, then you can add some CSS.  You'll need something like

```
.featimage {
width: 100%;
height: 450px; /** this can be edited to whatever height you want
}
```

Make sure the image appears below the header portion.

I suggest just going with the plugin.  It'll be easier for you.

Reference:  https://colorlib.com/sparkling/

Comment: without plugin, its possible to give image like that??

Answer (score 0):

you can use `background-size:cover` for making width 100% for background image in your background image class.

Comment: I give that image in featured image of wordpress post, In that how to I give background size??

Comment: I didn't use any HTML code.. simply I set it via featured image.. What I did is wrong means, Can u suggest what  code I need to do??

Comment: @Preethi try to add the css code I stated in my answer to see if it helps.

Comment: You set it via 'featured image' feature in WordPress. WordPress adds it to the HTML of the page via the specified functions in `content-single.php`. Those functions add a css class to the image of `.single-featured`.